# What is "cili algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology

I've read this notion in T. Matolcsi's Models In Mechanics. Google finds nothing about it. I think that this notion has some other common name and I am curious, what is it.

The definition of cili algebra in that book is the following (p. 196).

> A *cili algebra* is a normed star algebra such that the projections of
>   its completion form an orthomodular $\sigma$-lattice under partial
>   ordering and orthocomplementation introduced in 1.8.

The referenced 1.8 definition is this:

> Let A be a star algebra. We say that $p\in P(A)$ is less than or equal
>   to $q\in P(A)$, $p\le q$, if $pq=qp=p$.

The meaning of $P(A)$ is described so:

> Let $A$ be a star algebra. $x\in A$ is called a projection if
>   $x^*=x^2=x$. The set of projections is denoted by $P(A)$.

So, **what is the usual name of "cili algebra" in the mathematical literature?** Or if it's just that, then why isn't there any trace of it on the Internet? Where can be found this notion beyond Matolcsi's book?

The relevant pages of the book are these:

[image: p. 196]
[image: p. 197]
(the whole book can be downloaded from [this link](http://szofi.elte.hu/~szaboa/MatolcsiKonyvek/djvu/konyv/mechanics_ocr.djvu) in djvu format.)

Comment: Matolcsi is a Hungarian where ["cili" means blind](https://www.thenamemeaning.com/cili/), apparently.

Comment: @Conifold I think Cili is a [nickname of Cecilia](https://bestnicknametees.com/girls-names/letter-c-girls/cecilia/), and the [origin of Cecilia](https://www.behindthename.com/name/cecilia) is the Latin word *caecus* which means blind.